# Problems running hadoop on mac osx with default example

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

i installed hadoop using: brew install hadoop.

i have the following version installed:

```
hadoop version
Hadoop 2.3.0
Subversion http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1567123
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-02-11T13:40Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum dfe46336fbc6a044bc124392ec06b85
This command was run using /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar
```

why does the starting the single node cluster fails? does brew install hadoop install the 32 or 64 bit version of hadoop? i have a 64 bit system...

```
./start-dfs.sh 
14/04/03 13:29:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused
14/04/03 13:29:45 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

my ~/.profile looks like:

```
#Hadoop variables
echo 'Set Hadoop Variables...'
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
```

which test example could i run to verify that hadoop works fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you turn on **Remote Login** under **System Preferences** then **File Sharing**:

[image]

In order to check if it runs try `jps` command from command line. You should get something like:

```
43730 TaskTracker
43674 JobTracker
43730 NameNode
43582 DataNode
43611 SecondaryNameNode
43821 Jps
```

And now try some of the hadoop examples:

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.3.0/libexec/hadoop-examples-*.jar pi 10 100
```

Comment: hi, seems good so far: Job Finished in 14.751 seconds
Estimated value of Pi is 3.14800000000000000000